# Pascal autocompletion in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, pascal

Is there a snippet file or something to plug into Eclipse in order to be able to use autocompletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know. Syntax highlighting yes, but autocompletion is more complex.

Try Lazarus.